# JCheckBox customizado não aparece

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

Gostaria de exibir um `JCheckBox` com tamanho maior que o normal por padrão de interface. Após algumas pesquisas encontrei no link [Customize JCheckBox icons](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CustomizeJCheckBoxicons.htm) um exemplo para ser usado, porém ele não altera o tamanho do JCheckBox, e sim substitui sua imagem padrão por outras imagens que irão representar seus possíveis estados (mouse sobre o objeto, mouse fora do objeto, marcado, desmarcado, habilitado, desabilitado, etc.). Tudo bem, pois baixei imagens, editei de forma a atender cada situação.

Criei então uma classe chamada `ACheckBox` que extende `JCheckBox` para travar a definição dessas imagens para o `JCheckBox`, onde a classe ficou como ilustrado a seguir:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

import br.com.alutal.model.Constantes;

public class ACheckBox extends JCheckBox {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ACheckBox() {
        super();
        this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX));
        this.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX_CHECKED));
        this.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX_DISABLED));
        this.setDisabledSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX_DISABLED_CHECKED));
        this.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX_PRESSED));
        this.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX_ROLLOVER));
        this.setRolloverSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX_ROLLOVER_SELECTED));
    }

}
```

Como podem ver o caminho das imagens estão nas constantes, criando objetos `ImageIcon` como demonstrado no link especificado anteriormente.

Enfim, quando instancio um objeto `ACheckBox` infelizmente nada ocorre. Nem erro, e ele não aparece no painel. Se faço utilizando diretamente o `JCheckBox` aí funciona.

O que estou fazendo de errado? A questão do caminho da imagem, está correta pois são caminhos usados em outros objetos que funcionam (como `JButton` por exemplo).

O que será que pode ser?

Comment: Verifica se a imagem está carregando certinho. Se estiver usando o netbeans teste assim: crie um label, vá em propriedades, icon, ai clica no botão e selecione código personalizado, e então insira um de seus códigos: `new ImageIcon(Constantes.IMG_CAMINHO_CHECKBOX)` dá ok e vê se aparece.

Comment: @Dener, fiz o teste e não é o caminho da imagem. Coloquei ele em um dos objetos `JButton` do menu e a imagem apareceu normalmente.

Comment: como você adiciona nesse painel arrastando e soltando ou via código?

Comment: @Dener, estou colocando via código. To desenvolvendo via Eclipse sem uso de IDE gráfico pra montar formulário.

Answer (score 0):

**Daniel**,

Suponho que esteja adicionando o seu checkBox com um `jPanel.add(aCheckBox);` e seu painel painel possui um `layout livre`.

Dessa forma o `layout` do seu `jPainel` não sabe onde adicionar seu componente (por na direita, esquerda, em cima, embaixo, no meio, ...).

Repare que se você arrastar e soltar a classe de seu componente no painel (*se estiver utilizando o NetBeans*) seu checkBox aparecerá, ou ainda se mudar o `layout` do `jPanel` para outros layouts (Fluxo, Caixa, Grade etc) e usar o  `jPanel.add(aCheckBox);` aparecerá normalmente.

O `JPanel` com *design livre* utiliza o `GroupLayout`, se não quiser mudar o `layout` de seu painel para um dos que mencionei acima, você terá que adicionar com o `GroupLayout` (Dê uma [olhada aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) como utilizar ele!)

Comment: obrigado pela resposta e perdão pela demora na resposta. Eu estou utilizando o `MigLayout` como layout, utilizando o attributo `fill`. Como é um formulário, não tem como eu não usar um layout. Os objetos estão aparecendo todos normais, apenas o customizado que não aparece. Fiz os testes usando os mesmos caminhos de imagem em botões dos menus e confirmei que o problema não é o caminho da imagem...

Comment: @DanielChiurattoSeabra eu fiz um teste com seu código e não há nada de errado com seu `ACheckBox`. Poderia adicionar à pergunta a parte do código que você está inserindo e a configuração do seu MigLayout?

Comment: perdão pelo atraso no retorno. Vou dar como finalizado este tópico visto que houve alteração no layout do painel, e não irei mais usar imagem pra representar o `ACheckBox`. Muito grato pela atenção!